# I'm getting an error that says conflicting types in a C program

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm working on this assignment and I can't get it to run. I have tried many different things such as switching the position of the function isValid, but when I declare it before the function getGuess, the code will stop right after the function populateColorArray is called and will close the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLORS 8
#define THREE 3
#define FOUR 4
#define TEN 10
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

enum color {BLACK, GREEN, NAVY, ORANGE, PINK, RED, VIOLET, WHITE};

int main()
{
    srand((time(0)));

    int i;
    int j;
    char colors[COLORS] = {'B', 'G', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'V', 'W'};
    int secretCode[FOUR];
    int guesses[TEN][FOUR];
    int clues[TEN][FOUR];

    welcomeScreen();
    clearScreen();
    setCode(secretCode);
    printf("\n");
    clearScreen();
    displayBoard();
    populateColorArray(colors);
    initializeArray(guesses);
    getGuess(guesses, colors);

    for(i = 0; i < TEN; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < FOUR; j++)
            {
                printf("%c", guesses[i][j]);

            }

        }


    return 0;
}

void welcomeScreen()
{
    printf("                                     ###################################################################\n");
    printf("                                     ###################################################################\n");
    printf("                                     ########################                      #####################\n");
    printf("                                     ########################      Mastermind      #####################\n");
    printf("                                     ########################                      #####################\n");
    printf("                                     ###################################################################\n");
    printf("                                     ###################################################################\n");
    printf("Rules:\n");
    printf("1. The CodeMaker sets a secret code\n");
    printf("2. The CodeBreaker tries to match the code using logic and deduction\n");
    printf("3. After each move, the CodeMaker gives clues to the CodeBreaker\n");
    printf("4. The CodeBreaker has 10 attempts to guess the secret code\n");
    printf("\n");
}

// clears the screen for the next step of the program

void clearScreen()
{
    printf("                                    #########################\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("                                     <Hit enter to continue>\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("                                    #########################\n");

    char key;
    scanf("%c", &key);
    system("cls");
}

// board of the game

void displayBoard()
{
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|             SECRET CODE               |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|              ?  ?  ?  ?               |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|       PLAYER GUESS          |  CLUES  |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|    ?     ?     ?     ?      | ? ? ? ? |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------------------+\n");
}

//function has as an argument codeArray[] that later on it's used when calling the function convertColor

void setCode (int codeArray[])
{
    int i;
    printf("Integer Secret Code\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        codeArray[i] = getColor();
        printf("%d ", codeArray[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Color Secret Code\n");


    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
       convertColor(codeArray[i]);
    }
}

// function used to get the random colors

int getColor ()
{
    int colorRandom = rand() %COLORS;

    return colorRandom;
}

// function used to convert the numbers into an actual color string

void convertColor (int color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Black ");
            break;
         case 1:
            printf("Green ");
            break;
         case 2:
            printf("Navy ");
            break;
         case 3:
            printf("Orange ");
            break;
         case 4:
            printf("Pink ");
            break;
         case 5:
            printf("Red ");
            break;
         case 6:
            printf("Violet ");
            break;
         case 7:
            printf("White ");
            break;
    }
}

// function that receives the array color[] and prints the char equivalent to each color

void populateColorArray(char color[])
{
    int i;

    printf("\nCharacter colors are:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < COLORS; ++i)
        {
            printf("%c ", color[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
}

// used to set all row and columns of the array as -1

void initializeArray(int guesses[TEN][FOUR])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < TEN; ++i)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < FOUR; ++j)
                {
                    guesses[i][j] = -1;
                }

        }
}

/* function that is going to use isValid function to check if the user's
guess is valid and continue the game from there*/

void getGuess(int guesses[TEN][FOUR], char colors[])
{
    static int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int valid = FALSE;
    char guess[TEN];
    int i;

    while(valid = FALSE)
        {
            printf("Enter your guess of four colors (no spaces):\n");
            for(i = 0; i < FOUR; ++i)
            {
                scanf("%c", &guess[i]);
            }

        printf("You entered: ");

        for(i = 0; i < FOUR; ++i)
            {
                printf("%c", guess[i]);
            }

        if(strlen(guess[TEN]) == 4)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < FOUR; ++i)
                    {
                        guess[i] = toupper(guess[i]);

                        if (isalpha(guess[i]) == TRUE)
                            {
                                if(isValid(colors, guess[i]) == TRUE)
                                    {
                                        row = guess[i];
                                        col = guess[i];

                                        if(col == THREE)
                                            {
                                                valid = TRUE;
                                            }
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        printf("The value you entered is invalid");
                                        valid = FALSE;
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                printf("Invalid value entered %c, try again", guess[i]);
                                valid = FALSE;
                                break;
                            }
                    }



            }
            else
                {
                    printf("Incorrect number of letters entered");
                    valid = FALSE;
                }
        }
        row = row + 1;

}

// actually validates the user guess
// giving an error "conflicting types for 'isValid'

int isValid(char colors[COLORS], char color)
{
    int c;
    int valid = FALSE;

    for(c = 0; c < COLORS; ++c)
        {
            if(colors[c] == color)
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
        }
    return FALSE;
}
```

if anyone knows what else can I do to make it run, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Get rid of _all_ of the defines and replace them with an X-macro. Static sized objects are okay to declare, _eg_ `char colors[] = ...`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  when run through a compiler, with the warnings enabled ( I.E. `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) dozens of warnings (and some error messages) are output.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you pass a `char` to `strlen` instead of a `char*`:

```
if(strlen(guess[TEN]) == 4)
```

The result has *undefined behavior*. The `char` will be cast to a `char*` and it will start reading from that memory address. Not only that, `TEN` is out of bounds. The highest index you can use in `guess` is `TEN - 1`.
It should be like this instead:

```
if(strlen(guess) == FOUR)
```

Here, you assign `FALSE` to `valid` instead of checking the value:

```
while(valid = FALSE)
```

It should be:

```
while(valid == FALSE)
```

When you read the colors from the user, you do it character-by-character so `guess` will not be null terminated:

```
for(i = 0; i < FOUR; ++i)
{
    scanf("%c", &guess[i]);
}
```

Make that into something like this instead:

```
if(scanf("%4s", guess) != 1) {
    printf("try again\n");
    continue;
}
```

When you use the function `isalpha` you assume that it will return `1` (`TRUE`) if the `char` is alphabetic. That assumption is wrong. It will return non-zero if it's alphabetic.

```
if(isalpha(guess[i]) == TRUE)
```

should be

```
if(isalpha((unsigned char) guess[i]))
```

Here you take the argument `guesses`, but it's not used at all in the function, which is highly suspicious:

```
void getGuess(int guesses[TEN][FOUR], char colors[])
```

Also: You've defined your functions in the wrong order. Reorder them so that they are declared before they are used:

```
void welcomeScreen() { ... }
void clearScreen() { ... }
void displayBoard() { ... }
int getColor() { .. }
void convertColor(int color) { ... }
void setCode(int codeArray[]) { ... }
void populateColorArray(char color[]) { ... }
void initializeArray(int guesses[TEN][FOUR]) { ... }
int isValid(char colors[COLORS], char color) { ... }
void getGuess(int guesses[TEN][FOUR], char colors[]) { ... }
int main() { ... }
```